# Error MongoDB dateFromString with ISO-Date %G

Tags: mongodb

Dears, I want project a date ('2011-02-08') with format "%G-%m-%d" (Year in ISO 8601 format) and return current error

```
Mixing of ISO dates with natural dates is not allowed '\u0000'
```

My collection have that document:

```
{_id:1,date:"2011-02-08",message:"xxxxxxx"}
```

The query provides to mongo is:

```
db.comments.aggregate( [ {
   $project: {
      date: { 
          $dateFromString: { 
              dateString: '$date', 
              format:"%G-%m-%d"
          } 
        },
   }
}])
```

I want to do is convert the date in string format to the format indicated in the pipeline "% G-% m-% d" (I am using "% G" because I need to validate that the year is saved with the four characters)

How can I solve ?

Comment: Can you please provide what query you send to mongodb?

Comment: Thanks for answering me, there I made the edition

Comment: You saved date as string, check my answer. Such ISODate is mongodb internal format which converted from js Date saved to mongodb, and you need to use it as well.

Comment: Yes, maybe I explained badly...
 In your answer you use the pipeline "dateToString" but I need convert string to Date, therefore I use pipeline "dateFromString".

Comment: What I want to do is convert the date in string format to the format indicated in the pipeline "% G-% m-% d" (I am using "% G" because I need to validate that the year is saved with the four characters)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, haven't noticed that you actually need vice versa conversion. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "_id" : "22ETfCmrYYvPp68h4", "startDate" : "2017-05-24" }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $limit: 1 }, 
  { 
    $project: { 
      startDate: { 
        $dateFromString: { dateString: '$startDate', format: '%Y-%m-%d' } 
        }
      } 
  }])
{ "_id" : "22ETfCmrYYvPp68h4", "startDate" : ISODate("2017-05-24T00:00:00Z") }
```

Seems mongo doesn't like if you use iso format %G, which mathc ISO year, with %m and %d which said to be just normal stuff. I think you need to make issue on mongodb issue tracker to clarify this.

%Y though is same year of 4 characters, so maybe you just use it instead of %G, as it is actually working.